# How to use javascript varible in blade templete

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5, laravel-routing, laravel-blade

I want to use JavaScript variable in my laravel blade route.

here Is my code

```
   $(document).on("click", ".open-AddBookDialog", function () {


         var currentFieldID = $(this).data('field');
         $('.modal-body').empty();
         $('.modal-body').append('<iframe width="700" height="400" 
src=" {{route('add_image_dialog', ['field_id'=>'currentFieldID'])}}" frameborder="0" style="overflow: scroll; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: scroll; "></iframe>');
     });
```

Here I want to use currentfieldID  from my javascript variable

```
{{route('add_image_dialog', ['field_id'=>'currentFieldID'])}}
```

Comment: Blade is server-side, Javascript is client-side. You can't use a Javascript variable to load data from the blade engine because when Javascript gets executed, blade already rendered the template

Answer (score 0):

What @Fuzzyma pointed out is correct

You could instead generate the src url of the iframe client side, something like:

```
$('.modal-body').append('<iframe width="700" height="400" 
src="getSource(currentfieldID)" frameborder="0" style="overflow: scroll; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: scroll; "></iframe>');
     });

function getSource(currentfieldID) {
    var url = 'your_domain.com/';
    //add to url the currentfieldID somehow
    return url;
}
```